# Sql Query Result based on Condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have two put two condition in the result of a sql query result for the below function:

1. Table projects has two columns a_name and b_name and I want to exclude result in which b_name has value = xxxxx and value in a_name and b_name are same.

Below is currently used:

```
public function search_project_name($term)
{
    $params = array( ':term' => $term);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_name like '%$term%'ORDER BY projects.create_date DESC $limit";
    $stmt = parent::query($sql, $params);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
        $result[]=$row;
    endwhile;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Need `space` between `'%$term%` and `ORDER`

Answer (score 0):

You could add these condition with a `not` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   projects 
WHERE  a_name like '%$term%' AND
       NOT (a_name = 'xxxx' and a_name = b_name)
```

Comment: public function search_project_name($term)
 {
  $params = array( ':term' => $term);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_name like '%$term%' AND NOT ( project_name = 'XXXX' and project_name = builder_name ) ORDER BY projects.create_date DESC $limit";
  $stmt = parent::query($sql, $params);
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
   $result[]=$row;
  endwhile;
  return $result;
 }

Comment: public function search_project_name($term)
 {
  $params = array( ':term' => $term);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_name like '%$term%' AND NOT (project_name = 'XXXX') AND NOT (project_name = builder_name) ORDER BY projects.create_date DESC $limit";
  $stmt = parent::query($sql, $params);
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
   $result[]=$row;
  endwhile;
  return $result;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Problem part is `$term` in query so replace `$term` with `:term` try updated code:

```
public function search_project_name($term){
  $params = array(
    ':term'=>$term);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_name like '%:term%'ORDER BY projects.create_date DESC $limit";
  $stmt = parent::query($sql, $params);
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
    $result[] = $row;
  endwhile;
  return $result;
}
```

One more missing parameter is `$limit` you used in query but not passed to function?

With `$limit` as 2nd parameter default set to 10 rows:

```
public function search_project_name($term, $limit = 10){
  $params = array(
    ':term'=>$term);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_name like '%:term%'ORDER BY projects.create_date DESC $limit";
  $stmt = parent::query($sql, $params);
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
    $result[] = $row;
  endwhile;
  return $result;
}
```